# C# It does not appear in the DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

My folder show in treeview, folder click excelfilename show in my listview.

but, listview Double Click my excelfile Does not appear in datagridview.
ONLY READ.

This is my code.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Clear();

    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(treeView1.SelectedNode.Text);
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(treeView1.SelectedNode.Text, "*.xls*");
    foreach (string dir in dirs)

    {
        listView1.Items.Add(dir, 0);
        treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(dir);
    }
    foreach (string file in files)

    {
        listView1.Items.Add(file, 0);
    }
}
private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;

    {
        string name = "Items";                
        string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
        "textfile.xlsx" +
        ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;';";

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM [" + name+ "$]", con);
        con.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(data);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not using the selected listview item name i.e. `fileName` while retrieving data from database

Comment: `string constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
        "textfile.xlsx" +
        ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;';";` this only ever will load one file ("textfile.xlsx").. replace by fileName !